# Regex to eliminates anchor tags

Tags: java, regex

In my project code, I saw below regex is used to eliminate anchor tags and its attributes in string.

I am not familiar with regex. Appreciate your help on this.

String str2 = sql.replaceAll("]*>", "");

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/21 check explanation on right side.

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript. Removing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand regex-patterns, you can use the [regex online-tester tool](https://www.regex101.com/). That tool shows you exactly, what a regex-pattern does and you can also check if a string matches your regex.

To test your regex you have to add a `\` before your `/?` to escape the `/`:

```
<\/?a[^>]*>
```

Here the explanation:

> `<` matches the characters < literally
>
> - `\/?` matches the character `/`literally
>
>   - Quantifier: `?` Between `zero` and `one` time, as many times as
>       possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
>
> `a` matches the character `a` literally (case sensitive)
>
> `[^>]*` match a single character not present in the list below
>
> - `Quantifier:` `*` Between `zero` and `unlimited` times, as
>     many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
>
>   - `>` a single character in the list > literally (case sensitive)
>
> `>` matches the characters > literally

Answer (score 2):

Take the expression `</?a[^>]*>` step by step :

- `<` : character `<`
- `/?` : optionnaly followed by character `/`
- `a` : character `a`
- `[^>]*`: 0 or many characters that are not `>`. for example `href="..."`
- `>` : character `>`

Actually, it means : "replace `<a ***>` or `</a ***>` with `""` = nothing.

Example :

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">This is a link.</a>
```

becomes :

```
This is a link.
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/) to expalin and test regular expressions. 
For this particular one, i entered

```
<\/?a[^>]*>   (note i escaped the /  with a \)
```

And the text

```
hello <a href="blah" >  world</a>  here
```

And it gives an explanation on the right of

> </?a[^>]*>/ < matches the characters < literally /? matches the
>   character / literally Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many
>   times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy] a matches the
>   character a literally (case sensitive) [^>]* match a single character
>   not present in the list below Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited
>   times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>   > a single character in the list > literally (case sensitive)
>   > matches the characters > literally

It also highlights what it affects in the string.

Comment: This regex101 is really useful.

Comment: Please close this post.

Comment: It would be good if some one can able to close this post.